# VSCode breakpoints no binding with TypeScript npm linked package

Tags: typescript, next.js, vscode-debugger, npm-link

I have a Next.js app written using TypeScript with the following .tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Recently, we created a few private npm packages to share some code between apps, the .tsconfig looks like so:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

When we work on the package, we simply use `npm link <library-path>` and we run `tsc --watch` inside the package we are working on.
All this works well, the only issue is that when I try to debug, breakpoints doesn't bind.
If I add a breakpoint inside the dist/*.js files, it works.
I think it's related to sourcemaps, but I couldn't figure how.

If anyone has some ideas, I'd be happy to test them

Thanks

Mathieu

I tried various things that i've read online, new tsconfig params etc...
Never worked.

Answer (score 0):

download vscode 1.79.2 and install it.